# Allow 'subscriber' to upload media files - “Sorry, you are not allowed to attach files to this post.”

Tags: wordpress

I am using the Wordpress plugin "User Submitted Posts" to allow certain user to write posts from the front-end.

I don't want them to see other posts in the backend and I want them to have as little access rights as possible. Therefore I want them only to be "subscribers".

The only problem I have now is that "subscribers" are not allowed to upload files and therefore the "Add Media" button was not visible. I solved this by adding this code:

```
if ( current_user_can('subscriber') && !current_user_can('upload_files') )
add_action('admin_init', 'allow_subscriber_uploads');
function allow_subscriber_uploads() {
    $subscriber = get_role('subscriber');
    $subscriber->add_cap('upload_files');       
}
```

With this code the "Add Media" Button is there, the "subscriber" can access the media librabry (which is fine) and he is not allowed to delete other files (also fine).

But when I try to upload files in the front-end editor with a "subscriber" user the following error appears: "Sorry, you are not allowed to attach files to this post.".

I already tried to add more roles like this:

```
if ( current_user_can('subscriber') && !current_user_can('upload_files') )
add_action('admin_init', 'allow_subscriber_uploads');
function allow_subscriber_uploads() {
    $subscriber = get_role('subscriber');
    $subscriber->add_cap('upload_files');
    $subscriber->add_cap('edit_attachments');
    $subscriber->add_cap('edit_posts');
    $subscriber->add_cap('edit_published_pages');
    $subscriber->add_cap('edit_others_pages');
    $subscriber->add_cap('edit_others_posts');
    $subscriber->add_cap('level_0');
    $subscriber->add_cap('level_1');        
}
```

Unfortunately this still doesn't work, the same error appears. Any ideas why this doesn't work and which roles are necessary to make this work? Any other ways to solve this?

Another idea I had was to give them the "contributor" role and then make sure they can't access the backend but this seemed like the more complicated way than just allow a "subscriber" to upload media files.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same issue and saw this.  Solved my issue by adding 'edit published pages':

```
//Let Subscriber Role to Upload Media
if ( current_user_can('subscriber') && !current_user_can('upload_files') )
    add_action('admin_init', 'allow_subscriber_uploads');
function allow_contributor_uploads() {
    $subscriber = get_role('subscriber');
    $subscriber->add_cap('upload_files');
    $subscriber->add_cap('edit_published_pages');
}
```

Comment: This was already in the code from my post and it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

'edit published pages' command works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Then added

```
$subscriber->add_cap('edit_published_posts');
```

and it works.